# Checking for null in Javascript but still receiving TypeError

Tags: javascript

When I run this code, I receive this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of null
```

Here is my code:

```
let image = document.querySelector('.gallery__large-image-link');

if (image !== null || image !== '' || typeof(image) !== 'undefined') {
    var html = image.outerHTML;
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: console.log `image` and see what it returns! difficult to say without HTML

Comment: there should be  **&&** operator instead of **||**

Comment: Boolean logic fail

Comment: It'd be really great if you stopped deleting your questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809445/checking-for-null-in-javascript-is-not-catching-null-cases) just to re-make them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `||`, if *any* of the conditions are true, the block executes - and given the `!==` tests, the block will *always* execute. Use `&&` instead. Also, correct your `typeof` syntax:

```
const image = document.querySelector('.gallery__large-image-link');
if (image !== null && image !== '' && typeof image !== 'undefined') {
  const html = image.outerHTML;
  //do stuff
}
```

Or simply check to see if `image` is truthy:

```
const image = document.querySelector('.gallery__large-image-link');
if (image) {
  const html = image.outerHTML;
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Blanknewkid Eventhough this answer solved your issue. You still shouldn't check for existance of elements like that. Just simple check `if (image)` or `image instanceof HTMLElement`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this code

```
let image = document.querySelector('.gallery__large-image-link');

if (image) { // this will check for undefined and null
    var html = image.outerHTML;
    //do stuff
}
```